# bootstrap form label not aligned with checkboxes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

my checkboxes are pushed down and not aligned vertically with its label on the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ppjLyqg/

note: width must be >768px to see the issue

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="group" class="col-sm-3 text-right">Group*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="number" id="group" min="1" max="20" ng-model="member.group" maxlength="2" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="1" style="width:75px">
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 text-right">Office(s)*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8 checkbox" id="offices">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="0">Office 1</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="1">Office 2</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="2">Office 3</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="3">Office 4</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="4">Office 5</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "`col-sm-offset-3`" from div. You are already giving `col-sm-3` for label.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 text-right">Office(s)*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 checkbox" id="offices">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="0">Office 1</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="1">Office 2</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="2">Office 3</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="3">Office 4</label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox5" value="4">Office 5</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also there is a margin-top by bootstrap for check boxes. So if you want to align it with label, use `margin-top:0px;`

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/1ppjLyqg/1/